# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception React-native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApk'.
  >   A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-linear-gradient'.
  >   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':react-native-linear-gradient:_debugCompileCopy'.
  >   Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
  >          Searched in the following locations:
  >              file:/Users/omkaryadav/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.pom
  >              file:/Users/omkaryadav/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.jar
  >              file:/Users/omkaryadav/Documents/project/react/Archive/android/sdk-manager/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.jar
  >          Required by:
  >              project :react-native-linear-gradient > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.56.0
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 13.577 secs

Answer (score 0):

You have to link 3rd party libraries before building your project. That specific library you can link automatically by running `react-native link`.
If you didn't already, run `npm install` before command above.

Comment: npm install gives me a npm WARN

npm WARN @babel/plugin-check-constants@7.0.0-beta.38 requires a peer of @babel/core@7.0.0-beta.38 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

Comment: and react-native link 
RNFetchBlob checking app version ..
RNFetchBlob detected app version => 0.56
Add Android permissions => false
react-native-fetch-blob will not automatically add Android permissions after 0.9.4 please run the following command if you want to add default permissions :

 RNFB_ANDROID_PERMISSIONS=true react-native link